# Sharepoint Online JSON List Formatting: disable column in edit mode

Tags: json, gridview, sharepoint-online, edit, disable

In a SPO Modern List, in **"Edit in Grid View"** Mode, I need to **disable one column** from being edited using JSON.

Are you able to help me craft the JSON or point me to the specific element to modify?

Thank you!

Charlie

Comment: In the past, using SP2013, I just tweaked the CSS on the column I wanted to disable. Nothing fancy or deep checking in user security or anything. 
So, no CSS-disable or the equivalent is possible in JSON on a column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, SharePoint does not provide column-level security. But it is still possible to achieve your goal with a little creativity.

Here is a simple workaround to achieve it using Power Apps:

set the control type as view text:
[image]

As a result, when we edit the item, "text2" will be read-only:
[image]

Comment: This will disable column only on "list forms" not in "Edit in Grid View" Mode.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible using SharePoint online JSON formatting.

You cannot check if user is viewing list in normal/default list view or editing list in Grid view (Quick Edit) mode using JSON formatting.

**Documentation**: [SharePoint JSON formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)